# How to prove there exists $c$ such $f(c)f'(c)+f''(c)=0$

Tags: analysis

**Nice Question:**

> let $f(x)$ have two derivative on $[0,1]$,and such $$f(0)=2,f'(0)=-2,f(1)=1$$
>   show that:
>
> there exist $c\in(0,1)$,such
>   $$f(c)f'(c)+f''(c)=0$$

my try: since $$f(0)=2,f'(0)=-2,f(1)=1$$
so we easy 
$$f(x)=x^2-2x+2$$ such  this condition,But we can't use this function prove  this problem.

and other  idea: we can find this ODE
$$yy'+y''=0?$$

Thank you for you help！

Comment: Are you sure that there is no condition for the $f'(1)$...?

Comment: @passenger,there is no condition $f'(1)$

Comment: $y(x)= c_1 \tanh \left(c_1 x+c_2\right)$

Comment: $ff'+f''=D(f^2/2+f')$, but I don't immediately see a way of taking advantage (possibly passenger was hoping to apply Rolle's theorem to $f^2/2+f'$ :-)

Comment: @Norbert Mathematica reports that there is no $s,t$ such that $s \tanh (t)=2,s \tanh (s+t)=1,s^2 \text{sech}^2(s+t)=1$ which would be necessary for that to work.

Comment: @passenger Consider $f(x)=2-2x+x^2(1+(x-1) g(x))$ where $g$ is an arbitrary analytic function in $[0,1]$. The derivative $f'(1)$ turns out to be $g(1)$ which is arbitrary as well. And as far as I can tell the statement holds no matter what $g$ is taken.

Comment: This problem is not easy,+1,and I hope someone can slove

Comment: @Norbert. My solution looks very similar but your does not seem to satisfy the ODE. I suppose that you oversimplified. Please let me know if I am telling here something stupid. Thanks.

Comment: I'm tired of the commetns regarding that formula. OP asked sht is the solution of the naked differential equation. I've posted the answer. I was not posting the final answer, that was just a small help, nothing more.

Comment: @Norbert. Sorry to have been upsetting you.

Answer (score 14):

Following Jyrki Lahtonen's observation, let

$$g(x) = \frac{f(x)^2}{2} + f'(x). $$

Since $g'(x) = f(x)f'(x) + f''(x)$, it is sufficient to prove that $g$ has a stationary point. If this is false, then $g$ is either increasing or decreasing on $(0,1)$.

Suppose first of all that $g(x)$ is increasing. Let $d = 1$ if $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, and otherwise let $d$ be smallest such that $f(d) = 0$. For $x \in [0,d)$ we have that $-f'(x) \le f(x)^2/2$. Dividing through by the strictly positive number $f(x)^2$ we get $(\star$):

$$ \frac{-f'(x)}{f(x)^2} = \Bigl( \frac{1}{f(x)} \Bigr)' \le \frac{1}{2} \quad\text{for $x\in [0,d)$.}  $$

Since $f(0) = 2$, integrating gives $1/f(x) \le 1/2 + x/2$, 
or equivalently,

$$ f(x) \ge \frac{2}{1+x} \quad\text{for $x \in [0,d)$.} $$

It follows that $d=1$. Moreover, using the continuity of $f'$, we see
that

$$f(1) > \frac{2}{1+1}$$

unless equality holds in ($\star$)
for all $x \in (0,1)$.
Hence $f(x) = \frac{2}{1+x}$ and $f(x)f'(x) + f''(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$.

Now suppose that $g(x)$ is decreasing. 
Observe that if $f(d) = 0$ for some $d \in (0,1)$ then, since $f(1) = 1$, there exists $e \in (d,1)$ such that $f'(e) > 0$. Hence $g(e) > 0$. Since $g(0) = 0$ this is impossible. Therefore the same argument as before shows that

$$ f(x) \le \frac{2}{1+x} $$

for $x \in [0,1]$ and as before we get $f(x) = \frac{2}{1+x}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Would you please explain how we get , Since $f(0) = 2$, integrating gives $1/f(x) \le 1/2 + x/2$

Comment: Integrate $(1/f(x))' = -f'(x)/f(x)^2 \le 1/2$ from $0$ to $x$ using the initial value $f(0) = 2$ so $1/f(0) = 1/2$.

Comment: Ok. It is fine now. You have defined d. would you please explain what is d

Comment: I think first we may define d then we can use it.

Comment: Would you please explain ; It follows that $d=1$. Moreover, using the continuity of $f'$, we see
that

$$f(1) > \frac{2}{1+1}$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time. I read my answer again and believe it is correct and gives enough details. I hope you can find someone else to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, probably I do not understand the problem but it seems that one can do the following:

Consider the differential equation 
$$
f''(x) + f(x) f'(x) =0
$$
with boundary conditions $f(0) = 2, f'(0) = -2, f(1) = 1$.

Let's integrate it first time, thus we get:
$$
f'(x) + \frac{1}{2} f^2(x) = C_1
$$
$C_1$ we will find by applying the conditions for $x=0$:
$$
f'(0)+\frac{1}{2} f^2(0) = -2 + 2 = C_1
$$
Therefore, the new equation is:
$$
f'(x) + \frac{1}{2} f^2(x) = 0
$$
And it can easily be integrated:
$$
\frac{2}{f(x)} = x + C_2
$$
Applying the last condition which is $f(1)=1$, one can obtain:
$$
f(x) = \frac{2}{x+1}
$$
Seems like this function satisfies the equation $f'' + f f' = 0$ in any point of $(0,1)$, which means that one can always find a point $c$ such that $f(c)f'(c)+f''(c)=0$.

Comment: the proof would be over when we show that the differential equation with the given boundary conditions is well posed